# writing toggle function using jquery show and hide

Tags: jquery, toggle

How to write my own toggle function in jquery.

> ```
>     <head>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
>         <script>
>             $(function(){
>                 $('#dv').bind('click',function(){
>                     $("#toTgl:hidden").show();
>                 });
>                 $('#dv').trigger('click');
>             });
>         </script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <div id='dv' onclick="$('#toTgl').hide()"><center>Toggle</center></div>
>         <br/>
>         <div id='toTgl'><center>Change This</center></div>
>     </body>
> ```

Both (show & hide) gets triggered and I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came with and was working fine.

```
    <div id='dv' onclick="alert('test')">Toggle</div>
    <br/>
    <div id='toTgl'>Change This</div>
    <script>
    function toggle(){
        $('#toTgl')[$('#toTgl').is(':hidden')?'show':'hide']();
    }
    function toggleClick(ele){
        $(ele).removeAttr('onclick');
        $(ele).bind('click', function(ev){
            toggle();
        });
    }
    function z(id){ return document.getElementById(id);}
    toggleClick(z('dv'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the build-in [jQuery toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: I want an onclick event on the div elem too. how to that ??

Comment: you seem to do that right: 
`$('#dv').bind('click',function(){
    // do whatever you like
});`

Answer (score 0):

You have added two click events that conflict. Use a single event handler that shows and hides the element. (And don't use the deprecated `center` tag.)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#dv').click(function(){
        $("#toTgl").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  #dv { text-align: center; }
  #toTgl { text-align: center; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dv">Toggle</div>
  <br/>
  <div id="toTgl">Change This</div>
</body>
```

Comment: But I don't want to use this toggle method. I want write my own without using an 'if' condition.

Comment: @Artha: I don't really see the point, but you can avoid using `if` by using selectors as condition: `var x = $('#toTgl:hidden');var y = $('#toTgl').not(x);x.show();y.hide();`

Comment: I want an onclick event on the div elem too. how to that ??